# Run docker-compose without access to environment variables

Tags: windows, docker, docker-compose, environment-variables, command-line-interface

Is it possible to run a docker-compose.yml file without having access to the environment variables (on windows)? I have docker desktop installed successfully. Below is the docker-compose.yml.

Best,

```
---
```

version: '3.8'
services:
zookeeper:
image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:5.5.1
hostname: zookeeper
container_name: zookeeper
ports:
- "2181:2181"
environment:
ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000

broker:
image: confluentinc/cp-server:5.5.1
hostname: broker
container_name: broker
depends_on:
- zookeeper
ports:
- "9092:9092"
- "9101:9101"
environment:
KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://broker:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9092
KAFKA_METRIC_REPORTERS: io.confluent.metrics.reporter.ConfluentMetricsReporter
KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: 0
KAFKA_CONFLUENT_LICENSE_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR: 1
KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
KAFKA_JMX_PORT: 9101
CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: broker:29092
CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_TOPIC_REPLICAS: 1
CONFLUENT_METRICS_ENABLE: 'true'
CONFLUENT_SUPPORT_CUSTOMER_ID: 'anonymous'

schema-registry:
image: confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:5.5.1
hostname: schema-registry
container_name: schema-registry
depends_on:
- zookeeper
- broker
ports:
- "8081:8081"
environment:
SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME: schema-registry
SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_CONNECTION_URL: 'zookeeper:2181'

connect:
image: cnfldemos/cp-server-connect-datagen:0.3.2-5.5.0
hostname: connect
container_name: connect
depends_on:
- zookeeper
- broker
- schema-registry
ports:
- "8083:8083"
environment:
CONNECT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'broker:29092'
CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: connect
CONNECT_REST_PORT: 8083
CONNECT_GROUP_ID: compose-connect-group
CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-connect-configs
CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
CONNECT_OFFSET_FLUSH_INTERVAL_MS: 10000
CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-connect-offsets
CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-connect-status
CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER: org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER: io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: http://schema-registry:8081
CONNECT_INTERNAL_KEY_CONVERTER: "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter"
CONNECT_INTERNAL_VALUE_CONVERTER: "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter"
CONNECT_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
# CLASSPATH required due to CC-2422
CLASSPATH: /usr/share/java/monitoring-interceptors/monitoring-interceptors-5.5.1.jar
CONNECT_PRODUCER_INTERCEPTOR_CLASSES: "io.confluent.monitoring.clients.interceptor.MonitoringProducerInterceptor"
CONNECT_CONSUMER_INTERCEPTOR_CLASSES: "io.confluent.monitoring.clients.interceptor.MonitoringConsumerInterceptor"
CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH: "/usr/share/java,/usr/share/confluent-hub-components"
CONNECT_LOG4J_LOGGERS: org.apache.zookeeper=ERROR,org.I0Itec.zkclient=ERROR,org.reflections=ERROR

control-center:
image: confluentinc/cp-enterprise-control-center:5.5.1
hostname: control-center
container_name: control-center
depends_on:
- zookeeper
- broker
- schema-registry
- connect
- ksqldb-server
ports:
- "9021:9021"
environment:
CONTROL_CENTER_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'broker:29092'
CONTROL_CENTER_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
CONTROL_CENTER_CONNECT_CLUSTER: 'connect:8083'
CONTROL_CENTER_KSQL_KSQLDB1_URL: "http://ksqldb-server:8088"
CONTROL_CENTER_KSQL_KSQLDB1_ADVERTISED_URL: "http://localhost:8088"
CONTROL_CENTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: "http://schema-registry:8081"
CONTROL_CENTER_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
CONTROL_CENTER_INTERNAL_TOPICS_PARTITIONS: 1
CONTROL_CENTER_MONITORING_INTERCEPTOR_TOPIC_PARTITIONS: 1
CONFLUENT_METRICS_TOPIC_REPLICATION: 1
PORT: 9021

ksqldb-server:
image: confluentinc/cp-ksqldb-server:5.5.1
hostname: ksqldb-server
container_name: ksqldb-server
depends_on:
- broker
- connect
ports:
- "8088:8088"
environment:
KSQL_CONFIG_DIR: "/etc/ksql"
KSQL_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: "broker:29092"
KSQL_HOST_NAME: ksqldb-server
KSQL_LISTENERS: "http://0.0.0.0:8088"
KSQL_CACHE_MAX_BYTES_BUFFERING: 0
KSQL_KSQL_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: "http://schema-registry:8081"
KSQL_PRODUCER_INTERCEPTOR_CLASSES: "io.confluent.monitoring.clients.interceptor.MonitoringProducerInterceptor"
KSQL_CONSUMER_INTERCEPTOR_CLASSES: "io.confluent.monitoring.clients.interceptor.MonitoringConsumerInterceptor"
KSQL_KSQL_CONNECT_URL: "http://connect:8083"

ksqldb-cli:
image: confluentinc/cp-ksqldb-cli:5.5.1
container_name: ksqldb-cli
depends_on:
- broker
- connect
- ksqldb-server
entrypoint: /bin/sh
tty: true

ksql-datagen:
image: confluentinc/ksqldb-examples:5.5.1
hostname: ksql-datagen
container_name: ksql-datagen
depends_on:
- ksqldb-server
- broker
- schema-registry
- connect
command: "bash -c 'echo Waiting for Kafka to be ready... && 
cub kafka-ready -b broker:29092 1 40 && 
echo Waiting for Confluent Schema Registry to be ready... && 
cub sr-ready schema-registry 8081 40 && 
echo Waiting a few seconds for topic creation to finish... && 
sleep 11 && 
tail -f /dev/null'"
environment:
KSQL_CONFIG_DIR: "/etc/ksql"
STREAMS_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: broker:29092
STREAMS_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST: schema-registry
STREAMS_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_PORT: 8081

rest-proxy:
image: confluentinc/cp-kafka-rest:5.5.1
depends_on:
- zookeeper
- broker
- schema-registry
ports:
- 8082:8082
hostname: rest-proxy
container_name: rest-proxy
environment:
KAFKA_REST_HOST_NAME: rest-proxy
KAFKA_REST_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'broker:29092'
KAFKA_REST_LISTENERS: "http://0.0.0.0:8082"
KAFKA_REST_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: 'http://schema-registry:8081'

Comment: can you show your `docker-compose.yml` ?

Comment: @frank_lee I pasted it in the question :)

Comment: By default, the environment variables will not be carried into the container unless you specify them, you can check by executing `docker exec -it YOUR_CONTAINER_NAME bash` and  `env`. Not sure  it is what you want.